# Tomcat 8 reverse proxy

Tags: tomcat, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy with Tomcat 8. I've come across a few answers but I haven't made much progress since they refer to modules in httpd on apache server which I am not running. Is a reverse proxy on tomcat 8 without httpd possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy to use Apache mod_jk connector to connect Tomcat with Apache httpd. Follow these simple steps:

```
# mkdir mod-jk

# wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz

# tar -xf tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src.tar.gz

# yum install -y httpd-devel gcc gcc-c++ make libtool
# cd tomcat-connectors-1.2.41-src/native
# ./configure --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
# make
# libtool --finish /usr/lib64/httpd/modules
# make install

# service httpd restart
```

Now you can check /etc/log/httpd/mod_jk.log to confirm mod_jk initialized

Comment: @Fraser is that fixed your problem